# Splitting a polynomial into a list of its components

Tags: functions, polynomials, expression-manipulation

I was writing a program to analyze a polynomials components, and I was wondering if there was a way to split a polynomial into a list of its components. For example, splitting the polynomial `x^2 - 3x + 1` and have an output of `{{x^2}, {-3x}}`. I was thinking of using something like `FullForm` to get an output of `Plus[1,Times[-3,x], Power[x,2]]` and then using that to remove each component, but I wasn't sure how to implement that.

Comment: May be like this: `x^2 - 3 x + 1 /. Plus -> List`

Comment: @AnjanKumar `List@@( x^2 - 3 x + 1 )` is more robust. It'll also work on polynomials that are not fully expanded.

Comment: @yohbs Didn't know that possibility. Thank you.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

[MonomialList](http://reference.wolfram.com/mathematica/ref/MonomialList.html) does what you need:

```
Most @ MonomialList[x^2 - 3 x + 1]
```

> {x^2, -3 x}

```
Most @ MonomialList[(x + 2)^3]
```

> {x^3, 6 x^2, 12 x}

If you need to you can `Map` `List` on the previous lists to get a list of lists:

```
List /@ Most@MonomialList[x^2 - 3 x + 1]
```

> {{x^2}, {-3 x}}